# Best way to distribute a docker container to people with varying technical backgrounds

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm building an application that people will run on their own server, similar to moodleor wordpress. I'm assuming the people running the application will be familiar with executing commands on the command line, but I can't assume they are familiar with Docker.

What I'm thinking of doing, is giving them instructions on how to install Docker and docker-compose. Most installations will be small enough that both the web server and database can run on the same machine, so they can just they can just put the compose file in a directory and then run `docker-compose up -d`.

Would this be a good way to distribute the application? Ofcourse, the docker-compose file would take into account all the considerations for [running docker-compose in production](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two tasks:

**1. Install Docker on server**

You can use something like Ansible or just make a good manual page for them.

**2. Run containers, build application, etc.**

It is very easy to create Makefile with basic command:

- make install
- make reinstall
- make build
- make start
- make stop

If you will use Ansible for 1. you can use it for 1. and for 2. both.

If you don't need to automise 1. it is enough to use Makefile. It is simple and fast. And they can understand what does this Makefile do.

Answer (score 0):

I think, Why not? If your final user is Ok about using Docker, I think that's a cool way to do.

It let your final user get rid of versions and hardware differences, as you need, and you are able to push new versions of your containers, so that you can do updates easily.